# run exe on click of the button using js node in Adobe CEP

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe

I'm developing a js CEP panel for Adobe Premiere Pro.
I know how to run exe concurrently with my panel. Here is a simple code and it works:

```
var csInterface = new CSInterface();
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("myPath\\myApp.exe", function(err, stdout, stderr) {});
```

However if I want to run my exe file after clicking a button and add:

```
var openButton = document.querySelector("#open-button");
function openDoc() {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec("myPath\\myApp.exe", function(err, stdout, stderr) {});
}
```

the button doesn't work.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extendscript native method **File.execute()**
**Add function to Main JSX:**

```
function executeFile(path) {
  exeFile = File(path);
  if (exeFile.exists) {
    exeFile.execute();
  } else {
    alert("File not Found");
  }
}
```

**Main JS:**

```
///onClick
EXEPath ="path of executable file";
csInterface.evalScript('executeFile("' + EXEPath + '")');
```